# How to watch change in the state of an object globally stored

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuejs3, vue-component

i am using `vue3` with `options api`

i am learning how to use `global-store` i referred to the offical website of `vue`, and read some posts in forums.
as shown in the code in the followin link:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue-xltavx?file=src%2FApp.vue,src%2Fcomponents%2FHelloWorld.vue,src%2Fstore%2FStoreMajoreEnableState.vue

i create `StoreMajorEnableState.vue` as composable, and i want to `watch` the change in the state of `storeMajorEnableState`. to solve this issue, in the `app` component, i added the following

```
 watch: {
    'storeMajorEnableState_.state'(newVal, oldVal) {
        console.log('watch storeMajorEnableState_.newVal:', newVal)
        console.log('watch storeMajorEnableState_.oldVal:', oldVal)
    },
},
```

and

```
watch: {
    'storeMajorEnableState_.getters.getMajorEnableState()'(newVal, oldVal) {
        console.log('watch storeMajorEnableState_.newVal:', newVal)
    console.log('watch storeMajorEnableState_.oldVal:', oldVal)
    },
},
```

but neither of them solve the problem,
i would like to know how can i watch the changes occure to the state of `storeMajorEnableState`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For global state management, it is preferred to use `vuex`. It's setup is the same as you did above. Here's an example of how to setup a simple `vuex` store.

```js
import { createStore } from 'vuex'

const store = createStore({
  state: {
    count: 0
  },
  getters: {
    getCount(state) {
      return state.count;
    }
  },
  mutations: {
    setCount(state, payload) {
      state.count = payload;
    }
  }
  actions: {
    updateCount({ commit }, payload) {
      commit("setCount", payload)
    }
  }
})
```

Now I don't know why you want to watch a global state or what specific use-case you have for that, but if you call a `vuex getter` inside any of your components (preferably inside a computed property), then everytime your global state `count` is updated, the `getter` will be called again with the updated value. Hopefully this solves your problem.